# Why parameters in compareTo() is not accepting class name but only Object?

Tags: java

I am implementing Dijkstra Algorithm using Priority Queue in java. I am using objects of a class 'Node' for the queue. To implement this I am overriding the compareTo() method in Node class. It is working fine if I am using "Object obj" as parameters of compareTo(). However when I am giving "Node obj" as parameters to compareTo() an error is being diplayed saying "Node is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(Object) in Comparable." From what I have read this should be possible. What is wrong?

```
    public class Node implements Comparable  
    {   int key;  
        int val;  
        public Node(int v)  
        {   val=v;  
            key=0;  
        }

    @Override
        public int compareTo(Object obj)
        {   Node nd=(Node) obj;
            return this.key-nd.key;
        }

        public Node(int v, int k)
        {   val=v;
            key=k;
        }
    }
```

The error is being displayed if I do this(the code below) while the above code is working fine.

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Node obj)
    {  
        return this.key-obj.key;
    }
```

Comment: do this instead `Node implements Comparable <Node>`

Answer (score 2):

Comparable is an interface that specifies a parameterized type :

```
public interface Comparable<T>{...
```

We can also say that is a generic class (shorter).

So declaring `public class Node implements Comparable{...`
means that you want to implement Comparable with not a specific type.

In fact for the compiler `public class Node implements Comparable{` is the same thing as

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Object>{
```

So, the compiler expects to find a `public int compareTo(Object obj)` method in your class.
Whereas the compilation error message :

> "Node is not abstract and does not override abstract method
>   compareTo(Object) in Comparable."

Specify the class that you want to use in the Comparable interface you are implementing : (here `public class Node implements Comparable<Node>{`).

And the compiler will expect to find the implemented method:

```
public int compareTo(Node obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the interface ([Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)) you have overridden is not typed.  You need to use [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) to declare the type you want to compare:-

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>
```

This says that you want types of `Node` to be `Comparable` and will allow you to do

```
public int compareTo(Node obj)
```

If you don't genericise it, then you are effectively doing an `@Override` then changing the method signature, which your compiler will flag as an error because you are doing an `@Override` on a method not in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead,

```
public class Node implements Comparable <Node>{
```

This is because [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is a [generic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) interface, and as stated by the docs takes a parameter `T`

> `T` - the type of objects that this object may be compared to

Without this parameter, it resolves down to `Object`, which is something you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

```
Interface Comparable<T>
```

Is a Generic interface and since you are not binding any type the default is Object bind the required type (`Comparable<Node>`) and you'd be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The interface that you are trying to implement - `Comparable`, is generic. If you do not specify any generic arguments, the generic argument defaults to `Object`.

According to the interface, a `Comparable<Object>` should have this method:

```
public int compareTo(Object o);
```

But in your code, you only have this method:

```
public int compareTo(Node obj);
```

The compiler thinks that they are different and so complains.

To fix this, just specify a generic type argument. It's nothing difficult:

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>
```